# syntax highlight function arguments

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Trying to create a simple syntax highlighting for a special file type we use. 
within this file there are simple functions defined which I match using keywords:

```
syn keyword Funcs foo bar baz
hi def link Func Special
```

The functions can take arguments which are type-less: 
    foo(arg1, arg2, arg3)
The keywords take care of coloring the function name + parentheses but not the arguments. 
I would like to get those colored but cannot seem to get it to work.
Tried with :

```
syn keyword Funcs foo bar baz contains=arguments
syn match arguments "(\s*\w\+,*)\+" contained
hi def link Func Special 
hi def link arguments Type
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The `contains` shouldn't be used. A keyword is a keyword, it doesn't match anything before or after it. I think there's an option to match the following part as something, but I don't recall what it is. Maybe matching a region that covers both the function and arguments, and then including the keyword and argument highlighting in it, might be better.